# Texture paint oddities

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, texture-painting

I have a very unusual problem. In the texture painting mode, I noticed one oddity on my model.
[image]
[image]
When you try to paint on the texture, recalcitrant polygons appear that do not want to be painted over. Changing the uv does not solve the problem
Neither changing stroke or texture settings fixed the problem. I've tryed bleed and dither with different preferences, it does nothing.
Even more strange is that if you attach a cube to the model, unwrap it, and then delete it, the number of unpainted polygons will change.
The model is clean, without errors.

Normals are ok... The material of the body and head is the same.
It's funny, but if you delete naughty polygons and sew them up again, the model works. But I have no idea how to fix it normally.

[image]

Blender 3.5

Comment: Have you checked the normals? Or please share the file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Does the body have different material than the head?